# OpenCV (Saving frames )

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
count=0 

while(True):
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
   cv2.imwrite('frame1', frame)
   count+=1

   if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm new to programming and I need to open my camera and save frames in a folder.

```
Error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Harsh development\python tutorials\camera.py", line 12, in <module>
  cv2.imwrite('frame1', frame)
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-
python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:531: 
  error: (-2) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function cv::imwrite_
```

Could somebody provide me the solution or suitable code.

```
Operating system:  Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise(x64 based)
OpenCV 3.2.0
Python configuration - 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
cv2.imwrite('frame1.jpg', frame)
```

The error message you got:

> error: (-2) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function

openCV cannot decide on its own on the file format to be used for saving the image. The file format is usually defined via the file extension. For example:

- `'frame.jpg'` - saves the image in jpg format
- `'frame.png'` - saves the image in png format
- etc.

Comment: Thanks, it worked and saves the frame in my required python working directory.

Comment: I just need my first frame(so as to apply further image processing algorithms on it). It doesn't provide me single frame to be saved but multiple number of frames.

Comment: @HarshvardhanMatta if you need to save all of them just use  ` 'frame' + str(count) + ' .jpg'` for the name of the frame, that will save all the frames